# Delete last N elements if they are 0 and constant

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I have an array such as

```
data = [
  [1, 0],
  [2, 0],
  [3, 1], 
  [4, 1], 
  [5, 1],
  [6, 0],
  [7, 0]]
```

and I want the result to be

```
verified_data = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 1]]
```

So how can I remove the last elements if they are 0, and also if last N elements are same (except the first 1). What is the proper way to achieve this? Use of numpy is also fine.

Editing as I have written a solution even if it looks ugly:

```
def verify_data(data):
    rev_data = reversed(data)
    for i, row  in list(enumerate(rev_data )):
            if row[1] == 0:
                del data[- 1]
            else:
                break
    rev_data = reversed(data)
    last_same_data = None
    for i, row in list(enumerate(rev_data)):
            if not last_same_data:
                last_same_data = row[1]
                continue
            if last_same_data == row[1]:
                del data[-1]
            else:
                break
    return data
```

Comment: The result/explanation is not clear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this a little more? I do not understand what you are trying to do exactly. What does "constant" mean in this context?

Comment: by constant, I mean it doesn't change. if last elements are all 1, 1, 1, 1 then I only need the index of first 1 and discard the rest. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: By concatenate, you mean remove ? What is the interest of the first indice ? Is it just to retrack position ? Because without it, it would be far easier (and faster) to work.

Comment: Oh I confused the words. Should remove, not concatenate.

Comment: Yes, I need to preserve the indice

Comment: what do you want if last line is [7,2] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've split removing trailing zeros and removing trailing duplicates into two functions.  Using the list[-n] indices to avoid explicit index tracking.

```
In [20]: def remove_trailing_duplicates(dat):
    ...:     key=dat[-1][1]
    ...:     while (len(dat)>1) and (dat[-2][1]==key):
    ...:         dat.pop() # Remove the last item.
    ...:         key=dat[-1][1]  # Reset key to last item.

In [21]: def remove_trailing_zeros(dat):
            # len(dat)>0 can give an empty list, >1 leaves at least the first item 
    ...:     while len(dat)>0 and dat[-1][1]==0: 
                 dat.pop()

In [22]: data = [
    ...:   [1, 0],
    ...:   [2, 0],
    ...:   [3, 1],
    ...:   [4, 1],
    ...:   [5, 1],
    ...:   [6, 0],
    ...:   [7, 0]]

In [23]: remove_trailing_zeros(data)
In [24]: data
Out [24]: [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1]]

In [25]: remove_trailing_duplicates(data)
In [26]: data
Out[26]: [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 1]]
```

This works with the data you used in the question and checks for only one item left in the duplicates function.  What would you want for ALL data items being `[n, 0]?` An empty list or the first item remaining?

HTH

Comment: This actually crashes if all data elements are [n, 0].

Comment: Now corrected. remove_trailing_zeros is now more robust.

Comment: The first thing I check is, if they are all zero it returns empty array. But I guess your code handles that too. Thanks for beautiful code!

Comment: Glad to help. I think remove_trailing_duplicates can be improved. It doesn't need the assignment to key.